# Change matrix elements at specific locations?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, replacement, pattern-matching

Let's say I have an array

```
a={{1,2,3},
   {4,5,6},
   {7,8,9}}
```

I want to have all elements along the diagonal multiplied by 2.

```
{{2,2,3},
 {4,10,6},
 {7,8,18}}
```

What is the best way to do this? I tried

```
ReplacePart[a,{i_,i_} -> 2 a[[i,i]]]
```

and

```
a[[i_, i_]] = 2 a[[i, i]]
```

Which both gives the error

```
Part::pkspec1: The expression i cannot be used as a part specification
```

I suppose I can do

```
a*SparseArray[{i_,i_} -> 2,{3,3},1]
```

but I feel like there should be a simpler way to do this.

Comment: use `RuleDelayed` instead of `Rule`: `ReplacePart[a, {i_, i_} :> 2 a[[i, i]]]`

Comment: and use `Part` as `(a[[#, #]] = 2 a[[#, #]]) & /@ Range[3]; a` or `Table[a[[i, i]] == 2 a[[i, i]], {i, 1, 3}]; a`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `RuleDelayed` instead of `Rule` in `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[a, {i_, i_} :> 2 a[[i, i]]]
```

or, using `Part` assignment as in:

```
(a[[#, #]] = 2 a[[#, #]]) & /@ Range[3]
Table[a[[i, i]] == 2 a[[i, i]], {i, 1, 3}]
```

or, using `MapAt`:

```
MapAt[2 # &, a, Table[{j, j}, {j, 3}]]
```

or, using `MapIndexed`:

```
MapIndexed[If[SameQ @@ #2, 2 #, #] &, a, {2}]
(* or MapIndexed[If[Equal @@ #2, 2 #, #] &, a, {2}] *)
```

all give

```
(* {{2, 2, 3}, {4, 10, 6}, {7, 8, 18}} *)
```

By the way,  my favorite is your `a*SparseArray[{i_,i_} -> 2, {3,3}, 1]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know anything about `RuleDelayed`. Now I see why my code didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}

f = # + #*IdentityMatrix[Dimensions@#] &;

f@a

(* {{2, 2, 3}, {4, 10, 6}, {7, 8, 18}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all the good answers are taken, here is one for fun

```
m =  {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In this case, since the multiplier happened to be 2, you can just do

```
   LowerTriangularize[m] + UpperTriangularize[m]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and the diagonal will be doubled automatically. But this is only for this example only.
In the general case

```
n=2; (*or any other value*)
DiagonalMatrix[n*Diagonal[m]] + LowerTriangularize[m, -1] + UpperTriangularize[m, 1]
```